# XOR requirements for two input fields in a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, input

I have a form with several inputs. Most fields are required, but I want to set two of my inputs to XOR required. That is, one of the two must have a value, but not both.

Since this probably can't be done with pure HTML (correct me if I'm wrong), I'm guessing some javascript is in order, right? If so, what would I need? The input types are 'file' and 'url'.

**EDIT:** How about PHP instead of javascript? That would be preferred.

Comment: Do you want anything else sir?

Comment: I don't even know what to try. I'm mostly only a HTML and CSS user.

Comment: You should try to implement the test in PHP and, as convenience to users, also in client-side JavaScript. You need minimal amount of understanding PHP and JavaScript (and DOM) here.

Answer (score 0):

you can check value of two input with

simple if in php code

and echo result

```
 if((isset($input1) && ! isset($input2)) || (!isset($input1) && isset($input2)))
   {
   echo "yes";
   }else
 echo "no";
```